# number of pair of vertices with at least 2 distinct paths between them in a undirected graph

Tags: graphs

I need an algorithm to calculate number of pair of vertices with at least 2 distinct paths between them in a undirected graph
- the graph is connected
- distinct paths = distinct edges
ex: 
no. of vert = 3 and no. of edges = 3
and we have (1, 3) (1, 2) and (2, 3)
valid paths from 1 to 2 are 1-3-2 and 1-2
- count only pairs (a,b) with a < b
for example :

> 5(no. of vert) 6(no. of edges) : (1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 1) (3, 4) (4, 5)
>   (5, 4).

Output is 4 :

> (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3) and (4, 5).

Comment: I don't see any question here...

Comment: Do you want *distinct* paths or *disjoint* paths?

Comment: distinct paths, such in exemple

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're looking for the number of pairs of vertices having two *disjoint* *simple* paths connected them. A pair of vertices has two disjoint simple paths connecting them if they are in the same [biconnected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component). You can partition the graph into biconnected components in linear time. If the biconnected components have sizes $N_i$, then the number of pairs is $\sum_i \binom{N_i}{2}$.

Comment: A complete graph of two vertices is a biconnected graph (according to the definition used by this answer). However, the number of pairs of vertices having two disjoint simple paths connected them is 0, not $\binom{2}{2}=1$. A inequivalent definition of biconnected graph such as [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biconnectivity-in-a-graph/) would suit for this answer.